# Counting comparisons quicksort without global Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables, quicksort

I have a code of quicksort and counting comparisons that is working perfectly. But each time I call the function, the count keeps adding up again and again. Is there any way to avoid this?

```
count = 0
def quicksort(A, left = None, right =None):
    global count
    if left is None:
        left = 0
    if right is None:
        right = len(A)
    if left >= right:
        return
    p =A[left]

    i = left +1
    for j in range(left+1,right):
        if A[j] < p:
            A[i] , A[j] = A[j], A[i]
            i = i + 1
    A[left] , A[i-1] = A[i-1], A[left]
    quicksort(A,left,i-1)
    count += i-1-left
    quicksort(A,i,right)
    count += right-i-1

    return A,count+len(A)
```

Comment: That's exactly what you've asked it to do; you never reset `count = 0`.

Comment: If, specifically, you want this quicksort implementation to count the comparisons, consider computing it as a return value

Comment: @jonrsharpe If I remove the count=0, I get a error global name count is not defined.

Comment: @user3332615 ...of course, because it *isn't* defined; where did I suggest you should remove it?

Comment: @SimeonVisser Can you show me how to compute using a return value? I am new to coding.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry, I misunderstood. What is the alternative, then?

Comment: **Reset it**, put `count = 0` in *more* places, not fewer.

Comment: If I put `count=0` at more places, will it not affect the counting done each time a recursive call is made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make it work with a global `count`, you need to reset it at the first level of recursion. One way to do this is to move your implementation to a separate function `_quicksort` calling itself recursively, and reset the counter before the call:

```
def quicksort(A):
    global count
    count = 0
    return _quicksort(A)

def _quicksort(A, left=None, right=None):
    global count
    ...
    _quicksort(A,left,i-1)
    ...
```

In addition, this simplifies your main function signature as the `quicksort` end user does not really need to know about `left` and `right`.

Now, it is better not to use a global variable at all as it is a bad practice. Then, you need to somehow pass a context to the `_quicksort` function for it to know which counter to deal with. So you would need to pass something as a parameter:

```
def _quicksort(context, A, left=None, right=None):
    ...
    _quicksort(context, ...)
```

For example, this `context` could be a dictionary like `{'count': 0}` which you can then access as `context['count']`, or it could be an object to use `context.count`. Note that in this case this is getting really close to classes, where the context is the object itself and `_quicksort` would be a class method:

```
class _Quicksort(object):
    count = 0
    def _quicksort(self, A, left=None, right=None):
        ...
        self._quicksort(A, ...)
        self.count += ...
```

Finally, another common way to deal with the context in recursive functions is to pass and return variables "by value" such as:

```
def _quicksort(count, other_context, A, left=None, right=None):
    ...
    count1, other_context1 = _quicksort(count, other_context, A, left, right)
    ...
    return count + count1, other_context
```

But then you would end up with a cluttered method signature and would have to figure out what `count` means in this case and how to get the same result (which is a good exercise!).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation about the different ways of implementation. I understood about resetting the counter. I started coding recently, so I don't know much about classes but after this I am really interested in learning.

Comment: @user3332615, I'm glad to help! You should avoid using global state as much as possible, and classes help you with that by creating a local context that you can use instead of a global variable. This intro to python classes looks like a good starting point if you are curious: http://www.jesshamrick.com/2011/05/18/an-introduction-to-classes-and-inheritance-in-python/